# REGEXP_LIKE QUERY IN ORACLE DB

Tags: regexp-like

I need to currently match `00000012345` and `12345` in my `DB` search query.
I am currently using following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BPP.CHECK_REGISTER 
WHERE CHECK_NO like CONCAT('%',:checkNum)
```

for searching but here `%` can mean any character other than `0` hence I have replaced this query with following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BPP.CHECK_REGISTER 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (CHECK_NO,'^(0*12345)$')
```

but in this query I don't want to mention `12345` but mention it as a user entered parameter like the first query `:checkNum`

How do I rephrase the `REGEXP_LIKE` condition with only 2 arguments with user input `:checkNum` as oracle db allows only a maximum of 2 arguments. (another problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the parameter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BPP.CHECK_REGISTER 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (CHECK_NO,'^(0*'||:checkNum||')$');
```

Alternatively add the regex part to the user entered value (in your application code) before passing it to the query.

Comment: how do we use the same query from JPA ??

searchCriteria.append(" and REGEXP_LIKE (e.checkNumber,'^(0*||:checkNum||)$')");

this is not a defined standard in JPA ..
how do i rephrase this??